# How do I get the next line from a file

Tags: c++, getline

I am implemting a program using c++, and i have a problem of geting the next line from an input file. I used:

```
   const MAX 300;
   char oneline[MAX];
   ifstream in;
   in.open("input.txt);
   in.getline(oneline,MAX);
```

The function `getline` always gets me the first line in the file. The thing is, how can I get the next line in the file?

Comment: Show more code then.  I can't reproduce your problem; every time I call `getline`, I get the next line.  (To be fair, I've only ever used `getline` to get a `std::string`.  In your code, if your line is longer than 300 characters, you'll only get the first 300 of them in the first call, the next 300 in the next, and so on.)

Answer (score 3):

```
std::string line;    
while(in.good())
{
    getline(in, line);

    //do something with line
}
```

Since you're using C++ you should use std::string to read your lines.

Comment: No. You should use `std::string` *regardless* of whether you have a reason to limit your lines to a particular number of characters.

Comment: no ther is no specific reason but this while loop will get the next lines in the input file??

Comment: Yes, the loop reads each line into the string `line`. Then you have to do something with it.

Comment: -1 Because the answer is wrong.  On two counts: `in.good()` isn't really meaningful, ever, and 'in >> line' reads words, not lines.

Comment: in >> line is whitespace delimited, not line. use std::getline(), per the answer below.

Comment: @James oops, updated. but what's wrong with good()? "good(): The function returns true if none of the stream's error flags (eofbit, failbit and badbit) are set." Surely we should be checking for more than just eof? hence the use of good() over eof()

Comment: @badgerr The problem with `good()` is precisely that it includes `eof()`.  And until an input has failed, the results of `eof()` aren't well defined.  The function you want is `fail()` (which returns true for `badbit` and `failbit`, but not `eofbit`).  Or more idiomatically, just use the stream as if it were a `bool`; the necessary conversions are based on `fail()`.  Once an input has failed (and only then), you can use the other tests to try to determine why.

Comment: @JamesKanze I don't understand; do you mean to say that the condition in the `while` should not check for the end of file being reached? That would cause the `getline` function call to continue to be called despite the end of the file being reached, no?

Answer (score 2):

```
while (getline(in,line,'\n')){
    //do something with line
}
```

Comment: You don't need the last argument to `getline`; it is the default (and if you use anything else, the function is misnamed:-)).